# Can you set a weak_ptr<> in a ctor?

Tags: c++, reference

The following code fails to compile in Visual C++ 11 with this error:

> 1>c:\users\tony\documents\visual studio 11\projects\cpp11_ex1\cpp11_ex1\main.cpp(52): error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'Foo *const ' to 'std::weak_ptr<_Ty>'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar( weak_ptr<Foo> foo ) : _foo(foo) { printf("Bar(%p)\n",this); }
    ~Bar() { printf("~Bar(%p)\n",this); }
private:
    weak_ptr<Foo> _foo;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : _bar() { _bar = make_shared<Bar>( weak_ptr<Foo>(this) );  printf("Foo(%p)\n",this); }
    ~Foo() { printf("~Foo(%p)\n",this); }
private:
    shared_ptr<Bar> _bar;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> instance = make_shared<Foo>();

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that I can't create a `weak_ptr` from a raw `this` pointer. This causes an interesting series of problems.

1. Since I am attempting this in `Foo`'s ctor, `Foo`'s reference count is 0 (i.e. the `make_shared<>` in main hasn't returned yet).
2. I've discovered that I can create `weak_ptr`s *from* `shared_ptr`s... But if I change `Bar` ctor to take a `shared_ptr`, I the act of calling `Bar`'s constructor ends up destroying `Foo`! (Since `Foo`'s reference count is still 0, creating (and then destroying) a `shared_ptr` to `Foo` via a call to `Bar`'s ctor ).

All I really want to do is create `Foo`, have `Foo` create and *own* a `Bar`, but have `Bar` have a weak reference back to `Foo`. I really don't want to be forced into 2 part initialization here!

Comment: `weak_ptr` can only be constructed from a `shared_ptr` or another `weak_ptr` -- what makes you think what you're trying to do is possible in the first place?

Comment: This is a very confusing layout. What problem are you trying to solve, and how did you arrive at this design?

Comment: `stdio.h` has been deprecated for three standards.

Comment: @ildjarn - So it's not possible for 2 objects to reference each other? Where 1 of the objects was a clear owner of the other (because it created it in it's own ctor)?

Comment: @dicroce : It's not possible for `weak_ptr` to be created without having a `shared_ptr` first, and you have no `shared_ptr<Foo>` here.

Comment: @ildjarn - This seems like a real flaw as: 1) I like to use encapsulation (Bar is an implementation detail of Foo). and 2) I like to fully construct objects in my constructors... To get around this, I'd need to delay creating of Bar (perhaps until it was first used)...

Comment: @dicroce : Personally, I don't think using a combination of `enable_shared_from_this` and lazy-initialization of `Bar` (using e.g. [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/)) is all that painful. That said, it really does sound like you could rework your design a bit to avoid this issue altogether.

Comment: @ildjarn - Seems like enable_shared_from_this doesn't work in a ctor... which is the whole problem... (and lazy initialization is possible, but then every function that uses Bar would need to check if its valid before use)... Looks like I'm gonna have to live with pointers for my weak refs....

Comment: @dicroce : Right -- inside the ctor, `this` does not yet exist. This is why you need `enable_shared_from_this` ***and*** lazy-initialization of `Bar`. And not every function that uses `Bar` would need to check if its valid; they should all just use the same private accessor member function that performs the check + lazy-initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Foo` will be pointed at by a shared_ptr, and Bar will always be owned by a shared_pointer of Bar, then if Bar exists, Foo exists.  Ergo, you don't need a smart pointer in Bar.  (If I understand the problem correctly)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Foo;

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar( Foo* foo ) : _foo(foo) { printf("Bar(%p)\n",this); }
    ~Bar() { printf("~Bar(%p)\n",this); }
private:
    Foo* _foo;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : _bar(new Bar(this)) { printf("Foo(%p)\n",this); }
    ~Foo() { printf("~Foo(%p)\n",this); }
private:
    shared_ptr<Bar> _bar;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> instance = make_shared<Foo>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Kind of a bummer... I had hoped to replace all my pointer use (between objects anyway) with either shared_ptr or weak_ptr...

Comment: I understand, but when the pointed-at object is guaranteed to exist for the duration, there's not really a point.

Comment: The point is just code consistency. If weak_ptr could be created from a raw pointer, then where you saw it, it would mean there is a cycle here.... Pointers are sometimes used for other things, so the presence of a pointer won't necessarily mean their is a circular dependency...

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

`boost::weak_ptr<T>` is for *storing*, not for using.

You want to pass `boost::shared_ptr` objects, and then store them in the `boost::weak_ptr` objects (usually private).

```
struct Foo {

  Foo(const boost::shared_ptr<int> &data) : weak_data(data) {}

  boost::shared_ptr<int> getData() {
    boost::shared_ptr<int> data = weak_data.lock();
    if (!data)
      throw std::runtime_error("data is no longer valid");
    return data;
  }

private:
  boost::weak_ptr<int> weak_data;

};
```

Whether you throw or pass back and empty `shared_ptr<T>` is up to you.  If you cannot lock the object though, you shouldn't be passing it around anymore.  It really isn't valid at that point.

That being said, you may want to refrain from creating a shared pointer in that manner.  It isn't clear from your example if you *need* this design.  If you can redesign it in a way like Mooing Duck suggested you will be better off, in all honesty.

From similar experiences when I needed circular dependencies like this, it probably is not a simple construction scenario.  I would look at a two part constructor (static named constructor, or builder perhaps) to manage creating the two objects and ensuring that their references are valid.

Here is a quick example of a simple named constructor.

```
class Foo;

// Likely that this should be a child class of Foo
class Bar {
private:
  friend class Foo;
  Bar(const boost::shared_ptr<Foo> &foo) : weak_foo(foo) {}
  weak_ptr<Foo> weak_foo;
};

class Foo {
public:
  static boost::shared_ptr<Foo> CreateFoo() {
    boost::shared_ptr<Foo> foo = boost::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo);
    foo.bar = boost::make_shared<Bar>(foo);
    return foo;
  }

private:
  Foo() {}
  boost::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;
};
```

Here you control the invariant that your `foo` and `bar` variables are created correctly.

Comment: When I needed circular dependancies, I made them all children of a container, which "owned" the lot of them.  That doens't work for all scenarios, but worked for mine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a weak pointer in the absence of strong pointers to the same object, by definition. When the last strong pointer goes away, all the weak pointers turn null. That's all the weak pointers do.

Write your own function that returns a shared ptr to Foo (a Foo factory), and initialize the weak ptr in Bar from that pointer.

Comment: So you really can't set up Foo owning Bar, with Bar having a weak reference back to Foo... If Foo wants to create Bar in it's constructor?

Comment: @dicroce: then Foo ctor must create a strong ptr to itself too. You will have to decide how to return it to the outside world.